# echo json_decode data in php

Tags: php, json

I have a value from database in json_encode format.

```
[["Size: 10x24 (+150)","Backing: Black","Lines: 1","Border: No Border","Border Color: ","Flashing: No Thanks","Outdoor: No","Vertical: No","contoured cut: No","qty: 1","Text 1: Custom","Line 1: Red","Font 1: Arial"]]
```

I want to display it's `json_decode` format in table.

```
$options = json_decode($options, true);
```

Then I am trying to put it in foreach loop:

```
foreach ($options as $value)
{
    echo $value, "\n";
};
```

and the output is just `Array`.

```
echo('<pre>'); print_r($json); echo('</pre>');
```

`print_r()` returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Size: 10x24 (+150)
            [1] => Backing: Black
            [2] => Lines: 1
            [3] => Border: No Border
            [4] => Border Color: 
            [5] => Flashing: No Thanks
            [6] => Outdoor: No
            [7] => Vertical: No
            [8] => contoured cut: No
            [9] => qty: 1
            [10] => Text 1: Custom
            [11] => Line 1: Red
            [12] => Font 1: Arial
        )

)
```

But it does not look good. which is the better and easy way to echo json_decode data in php?

Comment: You have an array of arrays so you can try foreach ($options[0] as $value) and see if that works.

Comment: which way you wants data?

Answer (score 0):

This will print data in table.

```
$options = '[["Size: 10x24 (+150)","Backing: Black","Lines: 1","Border: No Border","Border Color: ","Flashing: No Thanks","Outdoor: No","Vertical: No","contoured cut: No","qty: 1","Text 1: Custom","Line 1: Red","Font 1: Arial"]]';
$options = json_decode($options, true);
echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach ($options[0] as $value)
{
    echo "<tr><td>";  
    echo $value;
    echo "</td></tr>";
};
echo "</table>";
```